# Editing Issue - My edit disappeared when I clicked save edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was editing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063812/nsdateformatter-very-wierd-issue) which took about 6 minutes of my time as there were a lot of edits to make.

When I clicked `Save Edits`, it returned me to the question but didn't notify me that my edit had been submitted for review like it usually does.

I checked my activity tab but it didn't show up there either under [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458679/ren?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). There were no errors shown to me during this process. I tried it a second time shortly after and the same thing occurred. On the third attempt a half hour later, I succeeded when submitting the same edit.

Why did the first two edit submission attempts fail without any indication of failure? Also, if there was an error, why was I redirected to the question in the same way you are upon successful edit submission?

The edit to the text I was making is as follows:

*(Note - Title was also updated and not placing in quote tags or code block as it doesn't display very well due to the code within it).*

---

I'm trying to solve a very weird problem. In my app I'm using NSXMLParser to parse feeds.
I have a pubDate tag to parse as well.

I have many varied date formats to parse to the NSDate, and most of them I'm able to parse. With 1 of them I have problem though:

```
<pubDate>2013-04-17T12:22:00.0</pubDate>
```

Here is my date formatting code:

```
NSArray *dateFormats = @[@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S",
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm Z",
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",@"EEE,dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
assert(inputFormatter != nil);
NSLocale *loacle = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
assert(loacle != nil);
[inputFormatter setLocale:loacle];

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentPubDate];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
NSDate *inputDate = nil;
for (NSString *dateFormat in dateFormats) {
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    if (inputDate) {
        break;
    }
}

NSLocale *hebrow = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
outputFormatter.locale = hebrow;
[outputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:3600*2]];
[outputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[outputFormatter setTimeStyle:NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard];
NSString *outputDate = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];
```

When I'm debugging I can see that `dateString` has a pub date but with `/n` at the end.
It looks like this `@"2013-04-17T12:22:00.0/n"`.

But with `NSLog(@"%@",dateString);` I get this:

```
2013-04-17 18:10:37.769 AppName[11651:f803] 2013-04-17T17:56:58.0
2013-04-17 18:10:47.674 AppName[11651:f803] 2013-04-17T17:17:28.0
2013-04-17 18:10:49.990 AppName[11651:f803] 2013-04-17T16:27:36.0
```

So the date doesn't get displayed. Anyone have any ideas?

---