# Delete [EDIT] sections in a question

Tags: discussion, edits, site-usage

I've asked a question here:
[Import error when importing python file from same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356810/import-error-when-importing-python-file-from-same-directory)

I've made about 5 edits to it as I've discovered more information and added information requested by others. I feel I have now distilled the problem (EDIT 5). Should I remove all the extra information (such as previous edits that add nothing) that is now irrelevant? It will make the question more concise, more likely to be read and therefore more likely to be answered.

Comment: relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202472/whats-wrong-with-putting-edit-in-the-body-of-a-post

Comment: You mean remove the "Edit" title only, or the whole previous parts?

Comment: remove entire sections for improved readability. Ahh didn't know about the EDIT moniker being bad.

Comment: Depends on the question. IMO, yours is a prime candidate for editing down for conciseness/readability.

Comment: The short version; edit the post so that when you're done it has all of the information in it now, but so that it *looks* like it has been there the whole time.  If someone saw an earlier revision and wants to know what information you've added through edits, there is a revision history for them to see that; you don't need to put the revision history into the post itself.