# Should we include [edit:] when we edit our post?

Tags: support, edits

I have seen many posts that contain something like:

> **Edit:** I would like to do this, but not with that way...

and so on.

Should we include this `Edit:` in our posts when we edit them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other posts like [What's wrong with putting "EDIT: ..." in the body of a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202472/369802) or [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/369802) seem to suggest that this is not needed.

It looks neater to instead edit your post and edit in the information in a way that makes sense.

This could mean adding a new paragraph at the beginning, middle, or end of your post, or adding in extra sentences in existing paragraphs, but not a separate 'Edit' or 'Update' section.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can they be automatically removed?

Comment: As far as I know, they can't. So if you see them, the best you can do is help a person out by editing them out yourself, and leave a nice edit message explaining what you did and why :)

Comment: @double-beep Just remember to fix *all* errors when editing posts. Close vote reviewers don't like to see 1-fix edits that leave other errors.

Answer (score 9):

Usually, no. In most cases, they're just noise, like [salutations and signatures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Users can already see that a post has been edited, and the revision history shows what has been added after the initial version of the post.

It *might* be helpful in some cases to indicate some sort of timeline, if there is some ping-ponging going on between the question and one of the answers. However, I'd prefer if the edit is indicated in a more natural way, e.g.

> I've tried the method described in the answer by user12345. However, that didn't work for me because of ...